# 404 Error after changing Default Proxy address in app.config

Tags: c#, proxy, app-config

I want to connect to the internet using WebClient in c#
the connection was successful but it stopped working after changing proxy configuration in app.config

this is the configuration

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy enabled="true">
    <proxy proxyaddress="http://192.168.10.33"/>
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

and this how I connect to the internet

```
public async Task<T> PostAsync<T>(string uri, NameValueCollection pairs)
        {
            byte[] response = null;

            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    response = await Task<byte[]>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        return client.UploadValues(uri, pairs);
                    });
                }
                catch (WebException e)
                {
                    Trace.WriteLine(e);
                    response = null;
                }
            }

            if (response != null)
            {
                string resultAsString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
                T result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(resultAsString);
                return result;
            }

            return default(T);
        }
```

Comment: Does your proxy server run on specific port and/or use proxy authentication?

Comment: @uteist I'm not sure how I can verify that, but I can tell you that this is the IP to our shared sever on our network domain.

Comment: I guess, that's most probably not a proxy server then but just a share.  Anyways, why would you need Proxy in your config? What's the actual requirement?